# How can I use the result of one SwiftUI function as a piece of search criteria in another function?

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I want to use the result of a SWiftUI Firebase query (derived from a function) and use that result in a another separate function.

I am fairly new to SwiftUI programming but I have a fairly good understanding of how to execute standard Firebase queries.

```
class getData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var uid: String = ""
    @Published var firstName: String = ""
    @Published var lastName: String = ""
    @Published var aid: String = ""
    @Published var artistName: String = ""
    
    init() {
        fetchUserDetails()
        fetchNestedUserDetails()
    }
    
    func fetchUserDetails() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let query = db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: "W0LEsCiwc1UemNrxS1K6")
        
        query.getDocuments { userSnap, error in
            guard error == nil, userSnap != nil else {
                print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                return
            }
            
            for doc in userSnap!.documents {
                self.uid = doc["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                self.firstName = doc["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
                self.lastName = doc["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
                print("User Details \(doc.documentID) => \(doc.data())")
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func fetchNestedUserDetails() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let query = db.collection("users").document("W0LEsCiwc1UemNrxS1K6").collection("artists")
        
        query.getDocuments { userSnap, error in
            guard error == nil, userSnap != nil else {
                print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                return
            }
            
            for doc in userSnap!.documents {
                self.aid = doc["aid"] as? String ?? ""
                print("Nested User Details \(doc.documentID) => \(doc.data())")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code shows the **getData** class which contains two functions:

- **fetchUserDetails** - this performs a simple Firebase query against my **users** collection
- **fetchNesterUserDetails** - this performs a nested sub-collection query against the document sin the **users** collection.

I am successfully able to retrieve all documents from the **users** collection and map them wherever I need to in my application.

The **fetchNestedUserDetails** query returns a document value called **aid**. I would like to take the **aid** value and use it in another function which queries a different collection called **artists**. However, each time I have tried this the function returns nil.

What is the best method to use to parse the **aid** value from **fetchNestedUserDetails** into my next function?

Comment: The function `fetchNestedUserDetails` doesn't *return* anything. It's sets a var `self.aid` within an asynchronous closure. If it were to return something it would be called like this `let myReturnedData = fetchNestedUserDetails()`.  Firebase is asynchronous and data is only available within the closure following the call. So - what to do? Explore completion handlers, escaping clause or IMO async/await API calls. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080647/how-to-add-an-unescaped-closure-swift-firebase/71082527#71082527). And the link the @PeterFriese blog in that answer.